# What are some job titles a recent physics grad (Bachelor's degree) would fit well into?

Tags: soft-question, education

Suppose a young person just finished a four-year degree in Physics (in the U.S.).  Suppose he did very well, in terms of grades and understanding the material.  But suppose he wants a break from studying and would like to work for a year or a few years before deciding whether to study further.  He needs a job.  But what sorts of jobs is he qualified for?  He didn't take any engineering classes as such, and he didn't specialize in anything.  He can write a simple computer program if he needs to, but a hacker he is not.  We need job *titles* in order to plug them into job search engines.

If you can say anything about the salary level he would aspire to with this level of education, that would be a nice plus.

(Please help me migrate this question to the Workplace if that would be a better fit.)

Comment: While this clearly isn't physics, I think it's a tough sell for a job to hire you if you might return to school a year or two later.   That's not a good investment for the company doing the hiring.   Internships might be possible but those don't pay very well.    I'm also, not an expert in this at all.  It's been many years since I job-searched and I never had much success applying with a mathematics degree.   Once I was in a company though, hard work made a good impression and I got promoted faster than normal but applying from resume, I never had much luck.

Comment: *"But what sorts of jobs is he qualified for?"* - sigh... probably no more than what he was qualified for before starting a four-year physics degree.  I recommend that you take the time off from studying to *study how the world actually works*.  If you show up for work on time and are eager and competent to take on responsibility (and take criticism as an opportunity to learn), you will likely be valuable to many employers since, I'm afraid, these qualities are getting harder and harder to find.  I interrupted my studies to run a small business and learned more there than I ever did in school.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics.

Comment: @userLTK - He's really tired of school.  If the job is a good fit I doubt he will leave quickly.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - I am not sure how he can plug himself into the working world.  But I can say that he has grown a great deal intellectually in these three and a half years.  /  I ran a small business once and I would not like to see this person do that.  He tends towards the obsessive-compulsive.  It's hard to run your own business and just walk away at 5:00.  /  He just completed a summer job where he worked hard and was valuable but made minimum wage.  We really need to find something that pays better.

Comment: aparente001, I'm certain I made less than minimum wage when I ran a small business but, as judged by later events, the value of the experience and knowledge gained *far* exceeded the minimum wage.  I agree that it's hard (actually, effectively impossible, i.e., a recipe for failure) to run your own business and "walk away" at 5:00 or any other time.  Check your premises - does "find something that pays better" mean a bigger paycheck or a bigger *payoff*?

Comment: @JohnForkosh - He can write a simple computer program if he needs to, but a hacker he is not.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - I ran a small business once and I would not like to see this person do that. He tends towards the obsessive-compulsive.  I'm glad it was helpful for you, though.

Comment: @JohnForkosh - I know this young man quite well, and his talents do not lie in that area, unfortunately.  There are some things he is good at, some he is not.  Writing and debugging computer programs is not an area where he has a natural aptitude, sadly.

Comment: @JohnForkosh - He can write a simple computer program.  And now I will make a sightly tangential comment.  My spouse is an experimental physicist, and writes programs when necessary.  Those programs are helpful but from my point of view (masters in computer science), their maintenance often ends up being quite time-consuming because of their lack of elegance.  Not everybody has what it takes to do what you do.  On the other hand, the young man who's job hunting right now may have some strengths that complement yours.  However, I don't know you.  You may be the quintessential Renaissance man!

Answer (score 2):

There is a plethora of information of this type available through the AIP and SPS. [Here](https://www.spsnational.org/careerstoolbox) is a link to their "Career Toolbox" (which includes a section "Common job titles of physics bachelor's degree recipients").

My advice to this hypothetical student would be that they are probably selling themselves short. I would pick a few areas in STEM that are of particular interest, and go from there.

Comment: Will check out your suggestions and report back (but not right away).  /  I have no idea where the selling himself short perception came from -- was it something I said in the question?  /  The large state school he went to (with, granted, a small physics department, but still!) did not give him the information you supplied in your answer.  (Shocking.)  I'm not supposed to say thank you on stackexchange but I hope you are picking up the gratitude vibes I am sending you telepathically.